# geth removedb vs removing data folder

Tags: go-ethereum, removedb

What is the difference between using `geth removedb` command vs just deleting the data folder. Are the two operations equivalent?

I need resync my geth node from begining as I want to use the new 1.13 `--state.scheme=path` feature to enable auto pruning. And, am wondering whether to use `removedb` or delete the data folder.